# How to create a last_modified field in oracle 9i?

Tags: oracle

I'm using Oracle 10g Express or Oracle XE. In the EMPLOYEES table I want to add another column call last_modified that automatically generate current date or date/time if it has been modified. I know there is this rowscn(timestamp) thing that's only available from oracle 10g onwards but I want to manually create one because my client is using oracle 9i but I only have 10g to do the testing. Also I've never use oracle before. This is for some integration project with Lotus Notes. Therefore if possible I want the date or date/time to recognizable by LotusScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column of type `TIMESTAMP` to the table (might not be available in the de-supported 9i version, but then just use `DATE` instead).

```
alter table employees add (modified_at timestamp);
```

Then create a trigger that is fired on update which simply sets that column to sysdate:

```
create or replace trigger update_modified
  before update on employees
  for each row
begin
  :new.modified_at := sysdate;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to

- add a modify_date / modified_by column to your table
- create a trigger that updates this column whenever the row is modified

Example:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_AUD_EMPLOYEE
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON EMPLOYEE
  FOR EACH ROW
begin

  if UPDATING then

    :new.MODIFIED_BY := user;
    :new.MODIFY_DATE := sysdate;
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: No need to fire that trigger for deletes or inserts if you are only doing the work when updating.

Comment: That's true - it was just an excerpt from an audit trigger template we use (where we insert an audit record when updating/deleting).

Comment: It might confuse someone who is completely new to triggers.